What's the correct way of expressing Residual Block with forward function of pytorch?
AFAIK there are 2 ways to express ResNet Block in pytorch:

Copy the input in the beginning, modify the input in the process, add the copy in the end.
Preserve the input in the beginning, create new variable in the process, add the input in the end.

Which leads to 2 kinds of code:
def forward(self, x):
    y = x
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.norm1(x)
    x = self.act1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.norm2(x)
    x += y
    x = self.act2(x)
    return x

def forward(self, x):
    y = self.conv1(x)
    y = self.norm1(y)
    y = self.act1(y)
    y = self.conv2(y)
    y = self.norm2(y)
    y += x
    y = self.act2(y)
    return y

Are they identical? Which one is preferred? Why?

They are identical. It's just depend on how you would like to code

It doesn't matter so long as the you retain some reference to the input.
At a high level, you are trying to compute output = activation(input + f(input))
Both methods shown accomplish this. As long as you don't lose the input reference or change input through an in-place operation, you should be fine.
For what it's worth, I would separate out the residual connection and the sub-block just for clarity:
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = ...
        self.norm1 = ...
        self.act = ...
        self.conv2 = ...
        self.norm2 = ...

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.norm1(x)
        x = self.act(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.norm2(x)
        return x

class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block):
        super().__init__()
        self.block = block
        self.act = ...

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.act(x + self.block(x))

